# What is the correct package name for importing MigLayout?

Tags: java, swing, netbeans, import, miglayout

FYI, I'm new to Java development and Netbeans!

I have downloaded the MigLayout jar files, both core and for swing, and added their path in the NetBeans 8.2 IDE under 'Tools->Libraries->Library_Classpath'.

My problem is that I'm trying to use the API MigLayout() but every package name that I've tried to import it results in the error "package 'Package_Name' does not exist"

The following package names fail at compile time:

```
import MigLayout;
import net.miginfocom.MigLayout;
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
```

The following package names only fail at run time:

```
import net.miginfocom.layout.Grid; 
import net.miginfocom.swing;
import net.miginfocom.miglayout;
```

Links to the MigLayout forum are broken, and none of the tutorials I've seen have the import statements. All I am asking for is a link to or list of the packages needed to use MigLayout.
If MigLayout is no longer supported, it would be nice to know that as well!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of all packages you mentioned, the following are actually working:

```
import net.miginfocom.swing.MigLayout;
import net.miginfocom.layout.Grid;
```

It is not enough to set the jar files in the library configuration of NetBeans (`Tools > Libraries`). You also need to set it inside your project to get your classpath working.

In the projects view, locate the directory called `Libraries` (JDK will be located there) and right click on it, then click on `Add Library` and choose the library where you defined your jar files, in your case `Library_Classpath`.